# Polyline with gradient across width in iOS Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, gradient, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline

I have iOS app with the Google Maps SDK integrated.
My route has default style and I'm able to change the color to be gradient in `length` via `spans`.

Is it possible to update polyline color and define gradient in `width` instead (like original Google Maps app has)?:

[image]

UPDATE:
I have added limited version by using two identical polylines with different styles but I'm definitely looking for a better solution:
[image]

I followed the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes) and didn't find any references of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this:

```
GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.strokeWidth = 5;

GMSStrokeStyle *greenToRed = [GMSStrokeStyle gradientFromColor:[UIColor greenColor] toColor:[UIColor redColor]];
polyline.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithStyle:greenToRed]];
polyline.map = self.mapView;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the documentation for more info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes

I use for example two gradients from blue to dark(black):

```
let brandBlue = GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.blue)
let nightBlue = GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.dark)
let gradientBlue = GMSStrokeStyle.gradient(from: .blue, to: .dark)

polyline.spans = [GMSStyleSpan(style: brandBlue),
                  GMSStyleSpan(style: nightBlue),
                  GMSStyleSpan(style: gradientBlue)]

polyline.map = mainMap.mapView
```